# Hover outside to fill out the whole page

Tags: css

I have a div in the middle of a page, how can I hover it outside to fill out the whole page? Here is a pic:

[image]

```
#div1 {
    width: 85%;
    height: 270px;
    border: 1px solid #663399;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 25%;
    background-color: #663399;
    border-radius: 20px;
    transition: width 1s, height 1s;
    transition: width 1s, height 1s;
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide your HTML code? What do you mean by "hover it outside"?

Answer (score 0):

Its work like this ✌

> ```
> #div1 {
>     width: 85%;
>     height: 270px;
>     border: 1px solid #663399;
>     padding-top: 20px;
>     padding-left: 20px;
>     margin-right: 25%;
>     background-color: #663399;
>     border-radius: 20px;
>     transition: width 1s, height 1s;
>     transition: width 1s, height 1s;
>     transition: outline 2s;
> }
>
> #div1:hover {
>       outline: 1080px solid rgba(102,51,153,1); 
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Two ways:
1) Use a parent container which has 100% of width and 100% of width, and make it hoverable.

like so:

```
<div class='hoverable'>
 <div class='your-middle-div'> 
 </div>
</div>
```

and CSS

```
.hoverable {
position: relative;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}

.hoverable:hover > .your-middle-div {
background: blue;
}
```

2) Use padding intead of margin to align in the center. Paddings react to hovering

Comment: in this ways it will stretch and every thing inside this div will be stretch too
so i used 

#div1:hover {
      outline: 1080px solid rgba(102,51,153,1); 
}